# Python multiprocessing issue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a small piece of code, written in python which has a Generate class which returns the next number when ever called.

```
class Generate:
    def iter(self):
        self.next1 = 1
        return self
    def next(self):
        self.curr = self.next1
        self.next1 += 1
        return self.curr

def generateNos():
    for i in xrange(3):
        print g.next()

g = Generate().iter()

generateNos()
generateNos()
```

And a function generateNos, which generate 3 Nos only. So when i call this function two times as below, i get output as:-
1
2
3
4
5
6

Now, When I spawn two processes for calling this generateNos(), I get the output as:- 1
2
3
1
2
3

The code for the same is:-

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
class Generate:
    def iter(self):
        self.next1 = 1
        return self
    def next(self):
        self.curr = self.next1
        self.next1 += 1
        return self.curr

def generateNos():
    for i in xrange(3):
        print g.next()

g = Generate().iter()

p1 = Process(target = generateNos)
p2 = Process(target = generateNos)

p1.start()
p1.join()

p2.start()
p2.join()
```

Now it seems this Generate class get re-initialized again in child process, which I don't want. How can i avoid this?

Wanted the same behavior as, calling generateNos twice one after another.

Any hack, so that Generate() object " g = Generate().iter()" doesn't gets called again in child proesses, It should be called only once in Parent Process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have the object shared between processes via shared memory or some other mechanism that allows them to actually share the same object instance.  Starting a new subprocess actually pickles everything you pass in to the child process then rebuilds a copy in the subprocess.

Comment: how.? I am actually using shared memory, but shared memory takes loads of time, as it takes read-write lock everytime it gets called. This is actually a very small instance of a bigger problem. How can i get rid of this. I don't wanted to use shared memory, wanted to make everything local, and then finally update in shared memory (Still Optimized)

Comment: You are already blocking on both threads in your main function by calling `.join()` on them, making your program behave as if it is single threaded anyway.  The only other option I can think of is setting up a queue between your parent process and the children, then having the children pull data from the queue, and the parent populate the queue whenever the queue length falls below some threshold you define.  If you are trying to share dynamic behavior (such as generator data generation) between multiple processes though, you should not be trying to avoid locking.  Asking for trouble...

Comment: The join() function was put in intentionlly. 
The only think I wanted is that the Generate() object doesn't get reinitialized in the child process again, any hack for this.?, it should be done only once in parent process that's it. Rest would be fine.

Comment: I just gave you 2 options.  Run your data through a queue, or use shared memory.  Do not try to use a single generator instance in 2 separate processes without locking.  Getting the next value from a generator is not an atomic operation, and is thus not thread-safe without locking.

Comment: No buddy, Queue is certainly not the great solution, I have to change the whole underlying architecture. Still can you give me some example using Queue or shared memory solving the same problem.

Also, I know generator is not an atomic operation, but I do not care about lock over here. I have made the application lock independent for the generator function like this, loads of details on this.

Comment: Something of this kind, if this is a child process, then that line shouldn't be pickled?

Comment: pickle>unpickle is the sole method of communication when spawning a child process.  After launched, you can communicate via shared memory, pipe, or queue.